# How to replace value in column of table on PostgreSQL+?

Tags: c++, database, postgresql, libpqxx

I use [libpqxx](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_c_cpp.htm) for connect to PostgreSQL DB in C++. I want to encrypt a column of table and replace it with current column. I write this:

```
int num;
cout << "Select Your COLUMN Number For Encryption: ";
cin >> num;

/* Create SQL statement */            
sql = "SELECT * from " + tbName;

/* Execute SQL query */
result R3( N.exec( sql ));

/* List down all the records */
for (result::const_iterator c = R3.begin(); c != R3.end(); ++c) {
    c[num].as<string>() = encnum->encryptionData(3,5,c[num].as<int>());
    cout << "Encryption = " << c[num].as<string>() << endl;
}
```

But the result is like before encryption. What's my wrong and how can I replace values to other values in a column?

Comment: If you are trying to update a table column, then you should execute an [update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/dml-update.html) statement.

Comment: Can you show me? I tried for one value with update, but I want to update the entire column. @karastojko

Comment: Did you try the [Brief example](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/) which has the update statement?

Comment: And how about, when I want to encrypt ID column?@karastojko

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding of your problem is you have a column of text or binary data and you want to update all rows in that column to cyphertext representing an encrypted version of the current content of the file.

There are two approaches.

1. select and update one row at a time.  Advantage is that you can more easily manage transaction size.  In other words in this case you update one value at a time and do the encryption in the client.
2. You could use something like `pg_crypto` which is a standard extension to encrypt the data and use a single update query to do this.  Note that this can take longer open write transactions limit what autovacuum can clean up.  Also keys need to be provided to the query and so you have the possibility of key disclosure in your logs.

There is a huge tradeoff between the approaches.  In PostgreSQL, usually client-managed encryption is done because of the key disclosure and management issues you get in the backend.  However other approaches exist.